# Scale pose/animation from blender to sims 4

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, scale

I use blender to create poses/animation for the game sims 4. What I want to do is shrink the sims very small in an animation. Please picture, "alice in wonderland" when she drinks the potion and becomes very small. In the blender I can scale it down but it the scale down will not animate, that aside in game it doesn't recognize the scale down at all , it will change limb length when I do other poses so why won't it recognize the scale down in size? any help in this area would be amazing.

Comment: You can just keyframe the scale... Or did you try that?

Comment: im very new to this program. i just treated it like a normal pose animation, i scaled it loc rot saved it exported it to sims studio tested it in game, it does move down but it does not shrink in scale. im not sure what key frames is by definition ill look it up and go from there.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the export format used, and what you have scaled, the rig object or the root pose bone or ...